# Prove that the set of eigenvalues of block matrix with blocks $A$ and $B$ is the union of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B,U,O$ four matrix of real entries. $A$ is a square matrix of size $m$, $B$ is a square matrix of size $n$, while $U$ is a $n\times m$ matrix of all entries $=-1$ and $O$ is a $m\times n$ matrix of all entries $=0$. Let us consider the square (block) matrix of size $n+m$:
$$M=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    A & U \\
    O & B \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$$
Prove that the set of eigenvalues of $M$ is the union of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. This property of determinants should follow immediately if we can show $\det M=\det A \det B$ but I do not know to prove this statement. Any suggestions please?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/prove-that-the-eigenvalues-of-a-block-matrix-are-the-combined-eigenvalues-of-its

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
M = \pmatrix{A&O^T\\O&B} \pmatrix{I & A^{-1}U\\0 & I}
$$
Now, you just need to show that the first matrix has determinant $\det(A)\det(B)$, and the second has determinant $1$.  The second matrix is upper triangular.