# Determine whether the matrix is positive/negative semidefinite/definite or indefinite.

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices

Determine whether the matrix is positive/negative semidefinite/definite or indefinite:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
2&2&0&0\\
2&2&0&0\\
0&0&3&1\\
0&0&1&3
\end{array}\right)$$
I already know that the answer is positive semidefinite because of the following statement:

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be two symmetric matrices. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite
2. $C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}A&0_{n\times m}\\0_{m\times n}&B\end{array}\right)$ is positive semidefinite.

However, I want to find whether it is positive semidefinite or not in a different way. I know that a matrix is positive semidefinite if its eigenvalues are non-negative, but determining the eigenvalues of a $4\times 4$ matrix is quite tedious. Is there a different approach to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: From [Prove that the eigenvalues of a block matrix are the combined eigenvalues of its blocks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/prove-that-the-eigenvalues-of-a-block-matrix-are-the-combined-eigenvalues-of-its), you can see that the eigenvalues of $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
2&2&0&0\\
2&2&0&0\\
0&0&3&1\\
0&0&1&3
\end{array}\right)$ are found by combining the eigenvalues of $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2&2\\
2&2
\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
3&1\\
1&3
\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: You could use the characteristic polynomial of $C$ being the product of the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$.